# How to mount BlackArmor 220 NAS on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: mount, samba, nfs, 19.10, nas

I want to mount BlackArmor NAS 220 on my Ubuntu 19.10 to `/media/BlackArmor`

**SOLUTION**

I was missing `vers=1.0` on the last `cifs` parameter. The command that works:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest,vers=1.0 //192.168.1.3/Public /media/BlackArmor/
```

**Original Question**

I tried following the official instructions here: https://www.seagate.com/em/en/support/kb/how-to-mount-nfs-and-cifs-file-systems-on-linux-with-the-seagate-blackarmor-nas-209791en/ and it didn't work.

I also tried following some other instructions, and nothing worked.

This is what I tried already:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o noperm //192.168.1.3/Public /media/BlackArmor/
mount: /media/BlackArmor: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program.

$ sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.3/DataVolume/Public -o username=***,password=***,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755 /media/BlackArmor/
mount: /media/BlackArmor: special device //192.168.1.3/DataVolume/Public does not exist.

$ sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.3:/Public /media/BlackArmor
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

The device itself is working and I can access it with `smb://ba-07***.local/` and see all the content.

Any ideas?

P.S. I want to mount it on startup, but that's another issue.

**UPDATE**
I now also tried this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=***,pass=***,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755 //192.168.1.3/Public /media/BlackArmor/
```

(which is basically the same as the second one, except I use `user` and `pass` rather than `username` and `password`) and I get this:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

When I check the `dmesg` I see this:

```
CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.1.3/Public/
No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

Comment: Might need `cifs-utils` installed.

Comment: @mikewhatever I have it installed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was missing `vers=1.0` on the last cifs parameter. The command that works:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest,vers=1.0 //192.168.1.3/Public /media/BlackArmor/
```

and if you want it in `/etc/fstab`, and with guest user RW support:

```
//192.168.1.3/Public /media/BlackArmor cifs guest,uid=myuser,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,vers=1.0,noperm 0 0
```